# Collections module is None when running unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to run unittest, checking result of some function.
However, when I do so, I'm getting an exception of

`my_default_dict = defaultdict(list)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

In order to test this func, I import my `Class A` which has function needed to be tested. Like this: `A.my_func`. This class also has external imports which I mock using `mock` module.
I tried to patch `sys.modules.collections.defaultdict` with actual `collections.defaultdict` (imported in test case), but no results, in function scope, `defaultdict` is None somehow.

Comment: what is `list` here? have you shadowed the built-in type `list` in your code?

Comment: No, I use ```defaultdict's``` constructor with builtin ```list``` as an argument.

Comment: Could we have a look at the whole (relevant) code? Here's the [\[SO\]: MCVE page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).